# Python: Help Me optimize this code.

Tags: python

I am looking to see if this code can be optimized.

```
def gB(a,b,c):  
    x=len(b)  
    d=a.find(b)+x  
    e=a.find(c,d)  
    return a[d:e]  

print gB("abc","a","c")
```

Comment: What do you mean by optimize? You have no error checking. Also, give a realistic example with output please. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would start optimizing this by making it legible to other people.

Comment: @Adam: I wouldn't call that optimization.

Comment: I would.  It optimizes the ability of others to improve the code.

Comment: @Mike: and that would make meaningless  phrases like: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" and will turn it into "Prepature optimization is the salvation" ... so, subjectively speaking you can say it is of course. In Software technology it is not, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of problems with your code that you probably should fix before trying to optimize it.

Firstly, it's undocumented and the naming is not helpful. I assume it is trying to extract a string between start and end markers.

Secondly, it gives an apparent match even if the start and/or end markers aren't found:

```
>>> print gB("abc", "d", "e")
ab
```

It would be much better to raise an exception or return None in this case.

As for the speed, I doubt you can get faster for finding strings than using the builtin string finding functions. They are written in C and no doubt had a lot of time spent optimizing them. If someone can implement string finding faster in Python then the people who wrote find need to go back and look at their code again.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
import re

def gB(a, b, c):
    return (re.findall('%s(.*?)%s' % (b, c), a) or [''])[0]
```

If you are talking about smaller code, I think the re module can help you.

Comment: You need to re.escape b and c if this is going to work for b = '.' for example.

Comment: I don't think you'd want to use `findall()`, only to discard all but the first match.